# "Due date of" or "Due date for"?

Tags: phrase-requests, dates

1. "November 10th is the due date for assignment 1"
2. "November 10th is the due date of assignment 1"

Are both correct? If so, which one is best?

I don't think it makes any difference but I will be using this to create an all-day event on my calendar.

Comment: Hi pug. Grammatically they are both correct but I think "for" is preferable. It suggests that on that date something is expected, or 'waited for'. Whereas "date of" slightly suggests that the assignment has an inherent date.

Comment: Just to add my own gut reaction, of, here, is usually within a phrase that is about a possession or association--no rules to reference, again, this is just a gut reaction. I probably wouldn't use "11/10 is the due date of assign1", unless I was going to use it in some sort of association: "And 11/11 is the due date of the exam. So the topic covered in assign1 is probably going to be part of the exam." Even still, I would probably use "has": Assign1 has a due date of 11/10. HTH

Comment: Thank you @OldBrixtonian and @theship! Feel free to add an answer so I can mark it as accepted.